# Calling a procedure from another file

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl

I'm trying to call a procedure which is is another file. What I've got so far results in an error:

**test.p**

```
DEFINE VARIABLE tmp AS CHARACTER.
      RUN sumWords.p(INPUT "Hello", INPUT "World", OUTPUT tmp).
DISPLAY tmp.
```

**sumWords.p**

```
 PROCEDURE sumWords:
        DEFINE INPUT PARAMETER i_firstWord AS CHARACTER.
        DEFINE INPUT PARAMETER i_secondWord AS CHARACTER.
        DEFINE OUTPUT PARAMETER o_returnWord AS INTEGER. 

        o_returnWord = i_firstWord + i_secondWord.
    END PROCEDURE.
```

> test.p passed parameters to sumWords.p, which didn't expect any.
>   (1005)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have created an internal procedure "sumWords" in "sumWords.p". sumWords.p does indeed not expect parameters.

Either change sumWords.p and remove the lines `PROCEDURE sumWords:` and `END PROCEDURE.`

That way the sumWords.p expects the parameters.

Or change the caller:

```
DEFINE VARIABLE hSumWords AS HANDLE NO-UNDO.

RUN sumWords.p PERSISTENT SET hSumWords. 

RUN sumWords IN hSumWords (INPUT "Hello", INPUT "World", OUTPUT tmp).

DELETE OBJECT hSumWords.
```

Comment: OBJETC should read OBJECT, can't edit as Edits must be at least 6 characters